# onclick update text before AND after javascript finished

Tags: javascript

I have a super simple question. I have an onclick function that takes a good 10 seconds to complete. Therefore I want to add a 'Loading, please wait' text while the function completes.

If I do this:

```
javascript:
function onclickFunction(){
    addPleaseWait();
    runSlowFunction();
    addFinishedText();
}
```

Then of course the end result is that the slow function runs first, then addPleaseWait and FinishedText run 2nd and 3rd. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: We MIGHT also be able to help with "runs slow function" to make it faster :)  Otherwise, this needs MORE clarity OR is simply a repeat of some "show waiting" which is very common here and elsewhere (probably already answered)

Comment: create a flag (isDone), run setInterval that will check this flag and run callback when flag changed

Comment: These functions make some kind of Async call? If yes you could achieve it easily with async/await.

Comment: I'm trying to update the html with this command which might be the problem. I think that it has to finish all the javascript before it executed DOM updates?
    document.getElementById('rem_disc').innerHTML += '<br>Updating, please wait';

Comment: the long function is a NetSuite client script UI mishmash basically.  It just loads and submits line items so i highly doubt anything can be done about that.

Comment: Ok guys, so setTimeout definitely works. My question is as to whether that is proper or not? I thought it was generally frowned upon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function call() {
  //your function here for example :
  $("#yourFunction").html("yourFunction is executing....");
  $("#test").html("Please Wait....."); // during your function
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#yourFunction").html("yourFunction is completed....");
    $("#test").html("done!!!!"); // after your function completed

  }, 1000); // if you need more or less time change here 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick=call()>Click</button>
<div id="yourFunction"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use ES6 function, I would suggest you use promise to run your function.

```
function onclickFunction() {
    startLoader();
    longFunction().then(function(data) => {
        // long function is done, remove loader
        return removeLoader();
    }) 
}

function longFunction() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        /*
        * the parameter resolve tell when to finish. If you pass a function, it will finish once all the instruction of the function is done.
        * the parameter reject is used to manage error.
        */
        resolve(function() {
            // Do you long function stuff
        })
    })
}
```

This method could seams a little bit complicated for what you are trying to achieve, but I think it is a great way to handle slow function. To make sure everythings comes in the right order.

If you wish to learn more about promise, look at this [Mozilla docs link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: You mean... `return removeLoader()`?

Comment: i get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement" error unfortunately. also, isn't the javascript supposed to finish before DOM command updates the html? This could necessitate a new approach
    document.getElementById('rem_disc').innerHTML += '<br>Updating, please wait';

Comment: for your first problem, remove the return statement into the `then`. Also, the dom will be updated once the promise returns, or in that case, your javascript finish to run.

Answer (score 0):

You need a callback in your slow function, for example

```
runSlowFunction(callback) {
  // ... do all slow things, and in the end, call your function
  callback();
}
```

& then, your onclick function changes to

```
function onclickFunction(){
    addPleaseWait();
    runSlowFunction(addFinishedText); 
    // pass addFinishedText as the callback,
    // which gets called after the slow function is done
}
```